# localhost keeps redirecting to a specific web-site

Tags: node.js, redirect

I wrote this simple http redirect js file (taken from a book)

And every time I write a new program using http module , it keeps redirecting me to the same site I wrote back that time; it's weird that there is not even a mention of that web site but it keeps doing that.

So I was curious what may be the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a site that people will help you with your problem, but you have to give more information.  This is a terrible question.  There are no examples.  No information about what is going on.  Please ask well worded questions, with examples and code.  All the context that we need.  What you did here was absolute garbage, and if I had the ability I'd vote you down to the depths.  If your question is posted lazily (and it is), then the people answering will be lazy too.  Piss poor job mate.  Cheers.

Comment: I'm going to guess your browser cached the redirect.  Clear your browsers cache.

Comment: That is what I did, but was just curious what might caused that browser behavior

Answer (score 0):

What might be the cause of the problem is the browser's cache.

Look at this:

```
User           Browser        Web
someurl.com -> someurl.com ->
                           <- Redirect to other.com
               other.com   ->
                           <- content of other.com
            <- content of other.com
```

If there is no cache, your browser will have to do all of that, and if someurl.com disappear, you don t know where to go.

So the browser keep the link in cache (sometime it keep entire webpage too, but that s not the problem), so the second time it can do that:

```
User           Browser        Web
someurl.com -> 
               other.com   ->
                           <- content of other.com
            <- content of other.com
```

One request less, faster, and you don t care about someurl.com anymore.

When you used http-redirect, your browser have cached the redirect, and so called the redirected link directly.